# Tabs not toggling in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sinatra, haml

I am using Darkly theme in bootstrap3 using Sinatra. I am trying to implement tabs using bootstrap3. But, tabs are not toggling i.e. when i open the browser only active tab is shown. When I click on "tab b", url changes, but the content in tab remains the same and the tab doesn't toggle to other tab. Please help.Should i include any bootstrap inks? Here is my Haml code.

```
!!!
%html{lang: "en"}
  %head
    %meta{charset: "utf-8"}/
    %title Job Tracker
    %meta{content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1", name: "viewport"}/
    %link{href: "./bootstrap.css", media: "screen", rel: "stylesheet"}/
    %link{href: "../assets/css/bootswatch.min.css", rel: "stylesheet"}/
    %link{:href=>"//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.1.1/darkly/bootstrap.min.css", :rel=>"stylesheet"}
    %link{href: "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite", rel: "stylesheet", type: "text/css"}/
    %link{href: "https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css"}


    :css
      .container {margin top :20px}
      body {padding-top : 70px; font-size : 18px; text-align: justify; font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive; }
      h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { text-align: center; font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive; }
    :javascript
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
       _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-23019901-1']);
       _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', "bootswatch.com"]);
         _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
       _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();



  %body
    .container
      %ul#myTab.nav.nav-tabs{style: "margin-bottom: 30px;"}
        %li.active
          %a{ href: "#a"} a
        %li
          %a{ href: "#b"} b
        %li
          %a{ href: "#c"} c
        %li
          %a{ href: "#d"} d

      .tab-content
        #a.tab-pane.fade.active.in
          %p Tab a
        #b.tab-pane.fade.in
          %p Tab b
        #c.tab-pane.fade.in
          %p Tab c
        #d.tab-pane.fade.in
          %p Tab d

  %script{src: "public/js/bootstrap.min.js"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its causing any issues, but I notice that you are including both bootstrap 3 and bootstrap 2.3

```
%link{:href=>"//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.1.1/darkly/bootstrap.min.css", :rel=>"stylesheet"}
%link{href: "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite", rel: "stylesheet", type: "text/css"}/
%link{href: "https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css"}
```

I don't know much about sinatra, however the structure looks ok. Try without the fade in's to see if you can get it working without those.

Also check in developer tools in your browser to see if there are any js errors.

Hope that gets you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. It worked. I had to include oly bootstrap 3. I has to a add js.This is altered haml code and it worked.

%head
    %meta{charset: "utf-8"}/
    %title Job Tracker
    %meta{content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1", name: "viewport"}/

```
%link{href: "./bootstrap.css", media: "screen", rel: "stylesheet"}/
%link{href: "../assets/css/bootswatch.min.css", rel: "stylesheet"}/
%link{href: "public/js/bootstrap.min.js"}/

%link{:href=>"//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.1.1/darkly/bootstrap.min.css", :rel=>"stylesheet"}/
%link{href: "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite", rel: "stylesheet", type: "text/css"}/

%link{href: "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite", rel: "stylesheet", type: "text/css"}/
/ HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries
/[if lt IE 9]
  <script src="../bower_components/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/respond/dest/respond.min.js"></script>


%link{href: "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css", rel: "stylesheet"}/
%script{src: "http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js", type: "text/javascript"}
%script{src: "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"}
%script{src: "http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js", type: "text/javascript"}
%script{src: "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"}
```

Comment: Hi there. I see you're new to the site, so to stick with the usual practice here I think you should add this code as an addenum (via edit) to your original question, and mark @AceWebDesign's answer as correct then.